# Wave function of particle and antiparticle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, wavefunction, antimatter, cpt-symmetry

The wave functions of particle and antiparticle are related by complex conjugation and wavefunction $Ψ$ must be complex for particle such as $n$, $p$. Is there way to prove this mathematically? Can we do this by using probability density?

Comment: It started as a convention in identifying the solutions of Dirac equation with particle and antiparticle, afaik https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Physical_interpretation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, physical descriptions usually cannot be proven in a mathematically sense. Of course they should make sense and therefore mathematically sound. 
In particular when it comes to particle and antiparticles which is a concept of relativistic quantum field theory (QFT), actually a wavefunction as it exists in quantum mechanics no longer makes sense. Because the concept of a wavefunction violates causality which is a ground-laying principle in QFT. Therefore it can only be spoken of (1-particle)-solutions of particular wave-equations as Klein-Gordon (K-G), Dirac etc., but these solutions are no longer wavefunctions in the proper sense. Neither it makes sense of speaking probability density, (unfortunately) the theory is much much more abstract.

I'll make a try to explain: the theory (QFT) dealing with particles and antiparticles is a multi-particle theory, therefore, and that is fundamental,
everything takes place in the Fock-space. The states the Hilbert space consists of are in the "particle number" representation. The consequence is that the operators act on these particle states. Above all, our dynamical variables are now fields which are represented by field operators (marked by a $\hat{}$).These field operators curiously look like wavefunctions, but are operators acting on particle states. For instance for the solution of the K-G-equation there is a field operator $\hat\phi$ fulfilling: $(\Box + m^2)\hat\phi =0$. 
In order to simplify, instead of neutrons or protons (spin 1/2), I will speak of pions which have no spin: $\pi^+$ and $\pi^-$. In the following strictly speaking, if I say "particle" I mean a $\pi^+$, and "antiparticle" I mean a $\pi^-$.
There are 2 corresponding field operators which fulfill the K-G-equation $\hat\phi$ and $\hat\phi^{+}$ (the latter is the adjoint operator to $\hat\phi$). We can write both operators in annihilation and creation operators. Furthermore $d\tilde{p} = \frac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3 2E}$ with $E=\sqrt{p^2+m^2}$:

$\hat{\phi}=\int d\tilde{p}( a(p)e^{-ipx} + b^+(p) e^{ipx})$

$\hat{\phi^+}=\int d\tilde{p}( b(p)e^{-ipx} + a^+(p) e^{ipx})$

In this picture the 1-particle solutions ("our old wavefunctions") only appear as matrix elements of
the field operators between particle states of the Fock space:
Here $|p\rangle$ is a 1-particle (with momentum $p$) state, whereas $|\bar{p}\rangle$ is a 1-antiparticle (with momentum $p$) state and $|0\rangle$ is the 0-particle state (vacuum).

$\langle 0|\hat\phi|p\rangle = e^{-ipx}$   and $\langle 0|\hat\phi^+|\bar{p}\rangle = e^{-ipx}$

$\langle \bar{p}|\hat\phi|0\rangle = e^{ipx}$   and $\langle p|\hat\phi^+|0\rangle = e^{ipx}$

We can observe that the field operator $\hat\phi$ act on particle states 
as the adjoint field operator $\hat\phi^+$ on antiparticle states and vice-versa. There is perfect symmetry.
We can then define the charge conjugation operator $C$ on the Fock space which is supposed to realize the symmetry between particles and antiparticles
by   $C a(p)C^{-1} = b(p)$   and $C b(p)C^{-1} = a(p)$, then we can observe:

$C\hat{\phi} C^{-1} = \hat{\phi^+}$.

Now one is inclined to forget of the operator status of $\hat\phi$ 
and define a similar operation on 1-particle solutions $\phi$ (as we are no longer in Fock-space a matrix like $C$ is sufficient):

$C\phi =\phi^{\ast}$

Our 1-particle solutions we developed $\hat\phi$ in all fulfill the K-G-equation, of course they should:

$(\Box + m^2)e^{-ipx} =0$   and $(\Box + m^2)e^{ipx} =0$

In particular we observe $Ce^{-ipx}= (e^{-ipx})^{\ast}=  e^{ipx}$.

Now we are inclined to conclude, the solutions $e^{-ipx}$ describe particles
and $e^{ipx}$ describe antiparticles. Yeah, we got it! Not really, only almost.
If one looks closely, $e^{-ipx}$ describes in-going particles in Feyman-diagrams, whereas $e^{ipx}$ actually describe out-going particles in Feyman-diagrams, or in case out-going antiparticles. Even $e^{-ipx}$ can describe an antiparticle, however an in-going one. A priori we don't know. Actually it has to be like this:
the free 1-particle solution does not know (much) about the charge of the object which is moving with momentum $p$. So the wave description for an in-going object (particle or antiparticle) should be the same. 
According to the Feynman-Stueckelberg interpretation we can however at least say that if $e^{-ipx}$ describes in-going particles, then $e^{ipx}$ can describe "in-going particles with negative energy running backwards in time", but not in-going anti-particles. The "in-going particles with negative energy running backwards in time" can be interpreted as out-going antiparticles moving forward in time. 
Therefore in general the charge conjugation operation on 1-particle solutions has no evident meaning as it has however on the Fock space. I prefer in fact to limit its definition on field operators in Fock space. 
For spin-1/2 particles like p, n or electrons, it is a bit more involved, but most of what I explained remains valid. Remember(for spin 0): $C\hat{\phi} C^{-1} = \hat{\phi^+}$. Yes. $C\phi =\phi^{\ast}$ still useful, but less meaningful. Critics are welcome! I also wrote this text to get some feedback on "my" interpretation (then you get an even better explanation than I did hehe). Finally,
I admit, I did not explain much about annihilation and creation operators, in that case this text would be even much longer than the actual one. To be found in every introduction to QFT.